# Calculating 12-hour differences for hourly data

Tags: r, group-by, time-series, average, summarize

I have data measurements that over a 10 day period that are recorded on an hourly basis with a sample provided below:

```
   Date_Time              Measure
   1/1/2021 05:00         430.1
   1/1/2021 06:00         430.2
   1/1/2021 07:00         429.8
```

First what I want to do is calculate the difference for every 12 hour period - that calculate the difference from 00:00 to 12:00 and 12:00 to 00:00 and so on.

Second I want to be able to find the maximum difference for this period of time.

This is all done in R, and I have only been able to find code for calculating averages or know how to calculate differences individually and not creating its own kind of column of data for it.

I have tried using diff(Measure, lag = 11) thinking that would calculate the difference between 12 hour periods but I kept getting the error:

```
   Error in mutate(., diff_12 = diff(Level, lag = 11)) : x `diff_12` must be size 265 or 1, not 254.
```

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: I am kind of at a loss for what to do using mutate() function, I did create a column noting the hour (on a 24 hour basis i.e. 0-24) but beyond that am blind.

Comment: Please add your attempts to resolve the problem to the question by editing it

Comment: **Please add the code you are currently using to the question by editing it** - this helps others to reproduce the problem, and to provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the cleanest line of code I wrote I used:

```
   mutate(diff = lag(Measure, 12) - Measure)
```

This answered my own question.